# Swift DispatchQueue with Firebase synchronously

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, grand-central-dispatch

I'm trying to fetch some data from firebase inside a for loop but it doesn't work.

I know I'm supposed to use DispatchQueue, but I can't understand how I'm supposed to use it with Firebase.

I got a loop:

```
for i in 0..<Exercice.workout.count{
    exercice = (Exercice.workout[i] as! [[Any]])[0][0] as! String
    print("Exercice: \(exercice)")
    self.endDeleteLastSerie(key: key, exercice: exercice, callback: {(status, endTime) in
        if status == "success"{
            print("do stuff here")
            let index = self.getIndexOfExercice(exerciceName: exercice)
            print("Index: \(index)")
            print("ExerciceName: \(exercice)")
        }
}
```

Inside my function endDeleteLastSerie I'm calling 2 firebase functions

```
func endDeleteLastSerie(key:String, exercice: String, callback: @escaping(_ status:String, _ endTime: Int)->Void){
        FirebaseWorkout.deleteSerie(key: key, exercice: exercice) { (status) in
            if status == "success" {
                //we set the end time to firebase
                FirebaseWorkout.updateEndExercice(exercice: exercice, callback: { (status, endTime) in
                    if status == "success" {
                        callback("success", endTime)
                    }else{
                        callback("error", endTime)
                    }
                })
            }
        }    
    }
```

**** Example of one of my firebase function ****

```
static func deleteSerie(key: String, exercice: String, callback: @escaping (_ status: String)->Void){
        let uid = FirebaseUsers.User.uid
        print("remove")
    Database.database().reference().child("users/"+uid+"/workout/"+self.workoutKey+"/exercice/"+exercice+"/series/"+key).removeValue { (error, DatabaseReference) in
            if error == nil {
                print("removed from firebase")
                callback("success")
            }else{
                callback("error")
            }
        }
    }
```

---

But what I'm getting is:

```
Exercice: Bench Press
remove
Exercice: Pectoral Fly
remove
removed from firebase
removed from firebase
do stuff here
Index: 1
ExerciceName: Pectoral Fly
do stuff here
Index: 1
ExerciceName: Pectoral Fly
```

I tried to add my for loop inside:

```
DispatchQueue.main.sync { }
```

or

```
DispatchQueue.global().sync(execute: { })
```

or

```
var _dispatchQueue:DispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "first", qos: .userInteractive)
```

then add my for loop inside

```
self._dispatchQueue.sync { }
```

But nothing work

How can I solve this ? and get

```
Exercice: Bench Press
remove
removed from firebase
do stuff here
Index: 0
ExerciceName: Bench Press

Exercice: Pectoral Fly
remove
removed from firebase
do stuff here
Index: 1
ExerciceName: Pectoral Fly
```

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by using a `DispatchQueue` here? The Firebase SDK already does all it's network interaction off the main thread. All it does on the main thread is invoke your callback/completion handler.

Comment: The thing is, I get value from my for loop after getting the callback from firebase. When I get the callback of firebase, I do.. let index = self.getIndexOfExercice(exerciceName: exercice) but I always get "Pectoral Fly" as exerciceName

Comment: I added 2 more print in the callback to let you understand better, what I'm getting. And I added the print as they show on the console log. @Frank van Puffelen

Answer (score 0):

We don't have enough code here to understand portions of the application.  However, it doesn't appear to be related to your Firebase code.  How is the Exercise.workout array being managed?

In your first code snippet:

```
for i in 0..<Exercice.workout.count{
    exercice = (Exercice.workout[i] as! [[Any]])[0][0] as! String
    print("Exercice: \(exercice)")
    self.endDeleteLastSerie(key: key, exercice: exercice, callback: {(status, endTime) in
        if status == "success"{
            print("do stuff here")
            let index = self.getIndexOfExercice(exerciceName: exercice)
            print("Index: \(index)")
            print("ExerciceName: \(exercice)")
        }
}
```

The for-loop is running through the Exercise.workout array and the functions you reference don't appear to be removing items from the array.  Of course, that could be elsewhere in the code.  Also, we don't know how the getIndexOfExercice function works.

Further, you are dealing with enclosures on different threads so the print statements can happen in various orders.  If you want these to happen synchronously, you'll need to add code to do that.

There are many ways of synchronizing threads and there are plenty of examples on StackOverflow or general google searches.

However I don't think this is the crux of your question so if this doesn't help you find the problem, you will need to supply more code around the array being used (and getindex function).